# How do you create an event to undo the previous event in WPF with VB.NET

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, events

I was wondering if there is any relatively simple way to essentially create an 'undo' button that would undo whatever event happened right before it. The problem is, I can't do it explicitly (for example, if the background was white, and then it became red, I can't just have the undo button reset the background as white). I can't do it this way because I won't know which event happened last, there could be a number of events that could have happened, and I don't want an individual undo button for every single event.

To provide an example, I have a few labels in a grid, and when I mouse over any label it changes to a bigger size, and all the other labels become a standard (smaller) size. However, sometimes one of the labels will already be a bigger size (from a button, or such) -- lets call this label1. So when I mouse over a different label -- lets call this label2 -- then label2 becomes bigger whereas label1 is small now. But when I move the mouse off of label2, I want label1 to be big again whereas label2 should be small again. Thanks for any help/ strategies in advance!!

P.S. I'm pretty new to WPF so the simpler the solution the better :) But anything is appreciated!

EDIT: I think an easy way of asking this is: Is there any way to create a MouseLeave event that undoes whatever was done by a MouseEnter event?

Comment: Just remember the state before the `MouseEnter` event and reset it in the `MouseLeave` event. [This article](http://nicoschertler.wordpress.com/2013/04/10/preserving-the-context-of-an-operation/) might be an inspriation. Although, if you're new to WPF, it might not be suitable for you.

Comment: @NicoSchertler I took a glance at it, it seems to be in C# and I'm more familiar with VB.NET so it's tough for me to understand, but I'll keep looking at it more closely. Thanks!

Comment: It's just about making it a bit more convenient. In your case you just need some variables, store the current state in them and reset the state afterwards.

Comment: @user2509180: if you want a progressive introduction to this technique have a look at: **http://pragmateek.com/c-scope-your-global-state-changes-with-idisposable-and-the-using-statement/**

Comment: @Pragmateek Great, thanks, I'll take a good look at that.
And to both of you- thanks for the replies, i really appreciate the help!

Comment: @NicoSchertler I tried your method but I'm still struggling. I defined 3 new variables for the 3 widths that will be changing. How do I find their current state, and how do i do this at various times? thanks again for any help

Comment: You can read and write `Label.Width` at any time. So in `MouseEnter` you would do `savedWidth1 = Label1.Width` and in `MouseLeave` `Label1.Width = savedWidth1`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't do VB so sorry for conventions, but this should work for you as a quick example:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel">
        <Label FontSize="10" Margin="10" MouseEnter="OnMouseEnter" >1</Label>
        <Label FontSize="10" Margin="10" MouseEnter="OnMouseEnter" >2</Label>
        <Label FontSize="10" Margin="10" MouseEnter="OnMouseEnter" >3</Label>
        <Label FontSize="10" Margin="10" MouseEnter="OnMouseEnter" >4</Label>
     </StackPanel>
 </Window>
```

code behind:

```
Class MainWindow

Dim _mouseLeaveSize As Double = 10
Dim _mouseEnterSize As Double = 20

Private Sub OnMouseEnter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)

    For Each child As Visual In stackPanel.Children
        SetLabelLeaveProperties(child)
    Next

    Dim label = CType(sender, Label)
    label.FontSize = _mouseEnterSize

End Sub

Private Sub SetLabelLeaveProperties(ByVal myVisual As Visual)

    Dim label = TryCast(myVisual, Label)

    If label Is Nothing Then
        'iterate thru children to see if anymore labels 
        For i As Integer = 0 To VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(myVisual) - 1
            Dim child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(myVisual, i)
            Dim l = TryCast(child, Label)
            If l Is Nothing Then
                SetLabelLeaveProperties(child)  'Enumerate children of the child visual object.
            Else
                l.FontSize = _mouseLeaveSize
            End If
        Next i
    Else
        label.FontSize = _mouseLeaveSize
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't see how this would help. Setting the font size to constant values was exactly what he did not want.

Comment: I think it is helpful, Nico. The only reason, I posted is because the questioner is having hard time to understand links that are in C# and possibly needed code sample to look at. And sure, instead of private fields, I could have done something different (capture/reinstate the previous font, or grabbing a default style), but it was just quicker to demonstrate the point of not having to undo the event - that seems to be the essence of the question, doing something during the event => setting/unsetting properties on similar controls.

Comment: @denismorozov Sorry it took me so long to reply, and thanks for your help. I think at this point some of these things may be beyond me, as I was hoping there would be a "LastEvent.Undo" type of easy solution hahaha that I couldn't find. I'm going to research everything you've said to try and better understand it, and I'll come back and try it out once I better understand. Thanks again!

Comment: @user2509180, try to run the code that I typed in. It compiles/runs and does what you were asking for. Put a couple of break points to see how it executes. Hope that helps.

Comment: @denismorozov Ok, thanks for the help! I ran the code, but I think it's missing the functionality I wanted. If I click on a label (I added a basic Click_Event, so that when you click each label it makes the font size = _mouseEnterSize), then when I mouseEnter on another label, then mouseLeave (say, to a blank part at the bottom), I want the label that I clicked to be the largest. That's the whole point of what I meant by undo, so that when the mouseLeave happens, the application reverts to the state it was in before the MouseEnter. I'm not exactly sure where the undo part is in this code.